# Can not inject RestTemplateBuilder with spring-boot 2.7.0

Tags: spring-boot

here is the code:

```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier(REST_TEMPLATE_XXX)
  public RestTemplate restTemplateteXXX(RestTemplateBuilder builder, Properties properties) {
     ...
  }
```

I get the following error with spring-boot 2.7.0:
**Could not autowire. No beans of 'RestTemplateBuilder' type found.**

With version 2.6.14 there is no error.
Cant find anything in the release-doc of 2.7.0
Anyone can help?

Comment: It is only an error in Intellij. Code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `RestTemplateAutoConfiguration` you can import into your configuration class. The `RestTemplateBuilder` does not come automatically with the spring 2.7 unless you have `@EnableAutoConfiguration` enabled

Example

```
@Configuration
@Import(RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Config{
}
```